# Python error handling two dependent tasks

Tags: python, error-handling

What's the best way to handle this? I want to create a file and add a record to a database, but if either one fails, I want to undo the other. It looks kind of messy to have a try, except, else with another try, except inside it to handle undoing the first task if the second fails.

```
try:
    open and write file
except:
    pass
else:
    try:
        add record to db
    except:
        delete file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using try/except is sufficient:

```
try:
    open and write file
    try:
        add record to db
    except:
        delete file
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

What you said you wanted to do and what the code does *might* be different. Depending on your implementation of `open and write file` you may be left with an undeleted file.

---

**Solution**

"Flat is better than nested" - The Zen of Python

```
try:
    open and write file
    add record to db
except:
    delete file
    rollback database session
```

You could take it a step further and create a context manager that you could use as follows:

```
with record() as rec:
    open and write record to file
    add record to db
```

Comment: Why would you "rollback database session" if a file IO error occurs? In other words, if a file IO error occurs, you have nothing to rollback in database session. So, you need another try/except to handle file IO errors.

Comment: @ElisByberi you are correct that if a file IO error occurs there is no need to rollback. You could nest another try/except but all you are avoiding is calling an unnecessary rollback. The penalty for an unnecessary rollback < penalty of nested messy code (which OP specifically wanted to avoid).